# sed or awk command to replace a variable with a json object like below

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have an object string in `{"name": "VAULT", "value": "jsakjkaj"},{"name": "IMAGE", "value": "busybox"}` format in a file called `ENV.json`.

i am assigning the content of `ENV.json` to a variable called `VAL` like below.

```
VAL=`cat ENV.json`
```

and i have a placeholder `%KEYVALUES%` in another file test.json . i want to replace `%KEYVALUES%` with `$VAL` like below

```
sed 's/%KEYVALUES%/'${VAL}'/g' test.json --> but this is throwing the error
sed: -e  expression #1, char 16: unterminated `s' command
```

Please help.

Comment: Anything which contains whitespace needs to be quoted. You want `sed "s/%KEYVALUES%/${VAL}/" test.json` (probably without the `/g` but put it back if you genuinely expect multiple matches on the same line).

Comment: @triplee this isn't a job for sed since sed doesn't understand literal strings and so that would fail given various values of `VAL`, e.g. `&` or `\1` or `/`.

Comment: Still a common FAQ; probably edit to redirect to a different duplicate than reopen.

Comment: Agreed but after searching the archives for as long as I'm willing to I don't know of a question to mark it as a duplicate of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat ENV.json
{"name": "VAULT", "value": "jsakjkaj"},{"name": "IMAGE", "value": "busybox"}
```

```
$ cat test.json
foo %KEYVALUES% bar
```

```
$ val=$(<ENV.json)
$ echo "$val"
{"name": "VAULT", "value": "jsakjkaj"},{"name": "IMAGE", "value": "busybox"}
```

```
$ val="$val" awk 'BEGIN{old="%KEYVALUES%"; new=ENVIRON["val"]} s=index($0,old){$0 = substr($0,1,s-1) new substr($0,s+length(old))} 1' test.json
foo {"name": "VAULT", "value": "jsakjkaj"},{"name": "IMAGE", "value": "busybox"} bar
```

If it were me, though, I wouldn't read ENV.json into a shell variable first, I'd just do it all in awk:

```
$ awk '
    BEGIN { old="%KEYVALUES%" }
    NR==FNR { new=(NR>1 ? new ORS : "") $0; next }
    s=index($0,old) { $0 = substr($0,1,s-1) new substr($0,s+length(old)) }
1' ENV.json test.json
foo {"name": "VAULT", "value": "jsakjkaj"},{"name": "IMAGE", "value": "busybox"} bar
```